# Why does this canvas line have color in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/28z7mb9r/2/

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255);";
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

In Chrome, the fiddle shows up as appropriately blue. In Firefox, it's black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Firefox is more strict about the formatting, and does not allow semicolons in the strokeStyle definition.

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
```

The above works as expected in both browsers.